# Because “away” and “from” have similar ideas, “away from” is a common collocation

Tags: meaning-in-context, understanding

> se16teddy:
> English verbs of motion feel almost naked without a little adverb such as up, down, through, over or away, at least in conversational English. The prepositional phrase adds additional information. Because “away” and “from” have **similar ideas**, “away from” is a **common** collocation.

[Source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ran-away-from-the-lion.3991810/#post-20464319)

---

"**Similar ideas**" means roughly "**similar meanings**".
I'd like to know what "**common**" means.

Comment: In this context it means commonly occurring or commonly used. That is, it's a collocation that occurs frequently or is used often.

Comment: In your first choice, do you mean "shared by the two words"? For example, if I say that you and I have a *common friend*, then that's a more specific meaning of common which means that the friend is one that we *have in common*. I.e. it's one that is shared by you and me.

Comment: @Brandin I have corrected my question.

Comment: "occurring or appearing frequently" according to Merriam-Webster

Comment: @gotube I'd say that the fact that “away” and “from” have similar ideas is not the reason why “away from” is a common collocation.   I'd like to know your take on that.

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss Are you asking about the etymology of the collocation "away from" or the meaning of "common"?

Comment: @gotube I can't understand how the fact that “away” and “from” have similar ideas is the reason “away from” is a common collocation. I'd like to understand that.

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss Then ask a second question about that. This question is about the meaning of "common".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with the comments by  Brandin, gotube,  and others. Here "common collocation" means simply that this two-word expression occurs frequently, or is often used by fluent speakers.